# select distinct all the customer who have more than one account

Tags: select, distinct

I have two tables  customer and account

customer can have more than one account

i would like to select only the customers who have more than one account
in the tables below.. i would like to joind the two tables and get in th result Robert and Manuel who have more than one account

i think we have to use HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT but not sure how?!

thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please observe the comments on your question.

Here is an ANSI SQL way to achieve what you're looking for:

```
SELECT MAX(customer.[NAME]) AS [Name]
FROM customer
INNER JOIN account
    ON customer.id = account.[customer.id]
GROUP BY customer.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This joins the `customer` and `account` table together on the customer id (note it's bad practice to use special characters like periods in column and table names, such as your `account` table's column `[customer.id]`). Then it groups by the `customer.id` field (which will appear multiple times as a result of the join to the `account` table). Next it uses the `HAVING` clause with the `COUNT()` aggregate function to filter out any rows that have less than 2 accounts. Finally since you want just the `customer.NAME` but we're grouping on `customer.id`, it uses the `MAX()` aggregate function so we can select `customer.NAME` (which will always be the same within the grouping of the `customer.id` for a given customer id).

Note you might want to consider the case where you have two different `customers` with the same name, e.g. another `Robert` with `customer.id` of `1004` (and your `account` table had two accounts for `[customer.id] = 1004`). Your request will give you two instances back of the name `Robert` without a way to distinguish between the two, so you should also select the `customer.id` as part of the above query.

Comment: It worked..Thank you very much for the answer and the detailed explanation :)

Comment: @RobertSalem Absolutely, no problem!